# All of a sudden CreateConversationAsync throwing "incorrect conversation creation parameters"

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

The below code was working perfectly fine to date and now suddenly it is throwing an exception.

We wanted the bot to greet personally a new member who was getting added to a Teams channel.
For time being we have fixed it by catching the exception and adding few null checks.
But still don't understand what is causing the issue.
Right now its seems an incorrect syntax is being fed to conversationParameters.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
TeamDetails teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.GetTeamDetailsAsync(turnContext, turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo().Id, cancellationToken);
        var teamsChannelId = turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetChannelId();
        teamsChannelId = teamDetails.Id;
        var serviceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl;
        var credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(_appId, _appPassword);
        ConversationReference conversationReference = null;

        var attachment = GetCard();
        var proactiveMessage = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment);
        foreach (var teamMember in membersAdded)
        {
            var conversationParameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                IsGroup = false,
                Bot = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
                Members = new ChannelAccount[] { teamMember },
                TenantId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId,
            };


            await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).CreateConversationAsync(
                          teamsChannelId,
                          serviceUrl,
                          credentials,
                          conversationParameters,
                          async (t1, c1) =>
                          {
                              conversationReference = t1.Activity.GetConversationReference();
                              await ((BotFrameworkAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(
                                  _appId,
                                  conversationReference,
                                  async (t2, c2) =>
                                  {
                                      await t2.SendActivityAsync(proactiveMessage, c2);
                                  },
                                  cancellationToken);
                          },
                          cancellationToken);
        }
```

Comment: which version of bot SDK you are using in the above implementation V4 or V3 ?

Comment: We are using V4 SDK version

Comment: First of all check in which line you are getting this error code and confirm V4 SDK have any new changes.